# Passing arrays in polymer

Tags: html, polymer-3.x

How to mutate an array passed from an external html file in a polymer web component

As stated [here](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/model-data), when the array is reated inside the component it can be accessed. My question is how to access the passed array

## html code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Welcome
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Testtt</h1>

<a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a>
<a href="{% url 'signup' %}">signup</a>
<button-element title='test'></button-element>
<dropdown-element users='{{users}}'></dropdown-element>
{% if users %}
<p>test</p>
<p>{{ users }}</p>
<p>{{ users.1 }}</p>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

## base.html

```
<!-- templates/base.html -->
{% load static %}
{% load polymerdep %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>{% block title %}Django {% endblock %}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

  <script src="{% static "node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js" %}"></script>
  <script type="module" src="{% static "src/components-app/dropdown-element.js" %}"></script>
  {% block link %} {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

## array Contents

```
users=['test1','test2','test3','test4']
```

## polymer js file

```
import { html, PolymerElement } from '../../node_modules/@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import '../../node_modules/@polymer/polymer/lib/elements/dom-repeat.js';

/**
 * @customElement
 * @polymer
 */
class DropdowmElement extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
    return html`
      <style>
      </style>

      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[users]]"><p>{{item}}</p></template>



    `;
  }

  static get properties() {
    return {
      users: {
        type: Array,
      }
    }
  }
  constructor() {
    super();
  }


}

window.customElements.define('dropdown-element', DropdowmElement);
```

The data is loading in html file and no errors are listed in console

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly users are defined somewhere out of scope of where you are using it. 
Can you link to a location where the code is running?

Comment: users can be accessed in html page directly. The values can be printed there. The if block in the html code works fine. The problem is while passing the array to the polymer element the data is not being populated. The data is shown in browser while inspecting the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here below, pass the array into Polymer. And after modifications pass the array outside ;

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-zjl38rpassing-arrays-in-polymer?file=index.html)

my-element.js:

```
static get template() {
    return html`
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[users]]"><p>{{item}}</p></template>
            <paper-button on-tap="_clickMe">STEP -2 Pass the array outside </paper-button>
        `;
  }

_clickMe () {
      this.push('users', 'Last Test')
      this._arrayChanged();
    }

_arrayChanged(){
   this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('array-changed', { bubbles: true, composed: true, detail: this.users }));
}

}
customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

index.html:

```
    <button id="button" onClick="_sendDataIntoPolymer()">STEP -1 Send data into Polimer.</button> <br> 
    <my-element id="myelement" users="{{users}}"></my-element>
    <pre id="preview"> Arrray outside </pre>

  <script>

    function _sendDataIntoPolymer(){
      document.getElementById('myelement').users = ['test1','test2','test3','test4']
    }
    document.addEventListener('array-changed', arr=>{
         document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML += arr.detail

    })
```

**EDIT:**  Or add an observer in order to pass array outside upon modified:

```
static get observers() {return ['_arrayChanged(users.*)']; }

_arrayChanged(){
   this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('array-changed', { bubbles: true, composed: true, detail: this.users }));
}
```